# Amazon EC2 cluster error Failed to provision ec2 instances because 'The requested instance profile EMR_EC2_DefaultRole is invalid'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to create a cluster using amazon aws console with default role.The cluster gets created and it remains in starting state for sometimes and then terminated with this error:-
Failed to provision ec2 instances because 'The requested instance profile EMR_EC2_DefaultRole is invalid'

I tried editing user Trust relationship of Default Role but again it says not authorized.ALso,I have logged in as root account.

Comment: In IAM dashboard, under `Roles`, do you see `EMR_EC2_DefaultRole`?

Comment: I was able to get by creating custom user role.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem when I was trying to follow the documentation of EMR.

I solved it by:
1. Creating a *user* in AWS Identity and Access Management(IAM). 
2. After I assigned this *user* to a 'group'(Create a new *group*). 
  2a. The group should have the *roles* that are being used(S3 and EMR). - Click on attachments and select all the ones are not 0.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this issue when creating an EMR cluster with terraform.
The custom EC2 instance profile and its IAM role must be named the same, otherwise the creation fails with error

`Failed to provision ec2 instances because 'The requested instance profile <iam_role_name> is invalid'`

The iam role got the relevant policy `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonElasticMapReduceforEC2Role` attached and the output of EMR_EC2_DefaultRole looks the same as the created role, except that role and instance profile are named differently.

It's weird because if you name instance profile and IAM role differently and the cluster will be created within amazon management console, the relevant instance profile can be chosen from the dropdown - which leads to the mentioned error, too.

For now I didn't get it managed to assign custom EMR service and autoscaling roles successfuly.